# Add two IP Addresses to an SPF Record?

Tags: dns, ip-address, spf

Hope someone can help...

I have two websites, on two different Droplets (with different IP addresses) hosted on Digital Ocean.

Both websites use the **same domain**, the first website is `mysite.com` and second website is `example.mysite.com`

I need to edit my `SPF` record so it can allow both IP Addresses to to use the domain `mysite.com`

When I use the correct IP Address the SPF record below works (for one of the websites).

`v=spf1 ip4:167.XX.XXX.40 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`

Let's say one droplet IP address is: `167.XX.XXX.40` and the other IP address is `167.XX.XXX.247`

How would I add both to the same SPF record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just include it after your first IP address. So

`ip4:167.XX.XXX.40 ip4:167.XX.XXX.247`

in that line you show

Note: I looked at mine and I have the letter 'a' before those and I don't recall what the "a" is for.

Comment: The `a` permits to the IP from the `A record` to send mails, it is not needed in the above record, since the IP is already listed with `ip4:`. As for your solution it is correct. Here is the whole record, just for convenience:

    `v=spf1 ip4:167.XX.XXX.40 ip4:167.XX.XXX.247 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`